# how to correctly render referenced entities in list when I have objects instead of numberic ids?

Tags: admin-on-rest

right now in order for the list to render properly I need to have this kind of data passed in:

```
row = {
   id: value,
   name: value,
   height: value,
   categories: [1,2,3,4]
}
```

how can I adapt the code so that a list works with this kind of data?

```
row = {
   id: value,
   name: value,
   height: value,
   categories: [{id: "1"},{id: "2"},{id: "3"},{id: "4"}]
}
```

when I try to do that it seems that it applies `JSON.stringify` to the objects so it is trying to find category with id `[Object object]`

I would to avoid a per case conversion of data as I do now..
it seems that I cannot do anything in my restClient since the stringify was already applied

I have the same issue when I fetch just one data row e.g in Edit or Create.. categories `ReferenceArrayInput` is not populated when categories contains objects

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using format?

https://marmelab.com/admin-on-rest/Inputs.html#transforming-input-value-tofrom-record

Might help transform your input value. Then you can use format() to change values back to the format your API expects.

If this does not work then you will have to probably create a custom component out of ReferenceArrayInput.

Comment: Michail, did you ever get a chance to try this out? I'm currently trying this approach and seem to be getting an error. The field doesn't seem to like using the format method. I reported a [bug](https://github.com/marmelab/admin-on-rest/issues/1517), but wondered if you ran into the same issue.